# Why does Heroku log using the server time rather than the Rails time zone?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, logging, time, timezone, heroku

UPDATE: Ok, I didn't formulate a good Q to be answered. I still struggle with heroku being on -07:00 UTC and I at +02:00 UTC.

**Q: How do I get the log written in the correct Time.zone ?** 
The 9 hours difference, heroku (us west) - norway, is distracting to work with. I get this in my production.log (using `heroku logs`):

> Processing ProductionController#create to xml (for 81.26.51.35 at **2010-04-28 23:00:12**) [POST]

How do I get it to write `2010-04-29 08:00:12 +02:00 GMT` ?

Note that I'm running at heroku and cannot set the server time myself, as one could do at your amazon EC2 servers. Below is my previous question, I'll leave it be as it holds some interesting information about time and zones.

---

Why does `Time.now` yield the server local time when I have set the another time zone in my `environment.rb`

```
config.time_zone = 'Copenhagen'
```

I've put this in a view

```
<p> Time.zone <%= Time.zone %> </p>
<p> Time.now <%= Time.now %> </p>
<p> Time.now.utc <%= Time.now.utc %> </p>
<p> Time.zone.now <%= Time.zone.now %>  </p>
<p> Time.zone.today <%= Time.zone.today %> </p>
```

rendering this result on my app at **heroku**

> Time.zone (GMT+01:00) Copenhagen
>
> Time.now Mon Apr 26 08:28:21 -0700
>   2010
>
> Time.now.utc Mon Apr 26 15:28:21 UTC
>   2010
>
> Time.zone.now 2010-04-26 17:28:21
>   +0200
>
> Time.zone.today 2010-04-26

`Time.zone.now` yields the correct result. Do I have to switch from `Time.now` to `Time.zone.now`, everywhere? Seems cumbersome. I truly don't care what the local time of the server is, it's giving me loads of trouble due to extensive use of `Time.now`. Am I misunderstanding anything fundamental here?

Comment: Hurts my head that there's even a thing known as "Rails Time Zone"

Comment: @Montagist is there a thing known as "Rails Time Zone"? The real world has time zones, I'm happy we've got this awesome lib to help us deal with it.

Answer (score 76, accepted):

After some further investigation into my own Heroku timezone problems, I found a post which indicates that you actually *can* specify the timezone at an application level, using the following command:

```
heroku config:add TZ=Europe/Oslo
```

I believe this may be the answer to all your troubles. Courtesy of http://www.reality.hk/articles/2010/01/07/1319/ (**Edit:**  Broken link as of 2012.08.23.  [Archived copy](http://web.archive.org/web/20100525142324/http://www.reality.hk/articles/2010/01/07/1319/).)

Comment: Does this config also affect heroku addon databases?

Comment: Just in case anyone else is chasing it, the timezone options can be found on wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones

Comment: Also rake time:zones:all can be helpful

Comment: I tried this, but there was no change in the timezone of the logs.

Comment: I worked to me `heroku config:add TZ="America/Sao_Paulo"`

Answer (score 3):

Without being able to change the actual server time (which I don't think you'll be able to do on Heroku), your only option is to convert the times yourself.

If `Time.zone.now` is too cumbersome, you could set a global timezone using the [tzinfo](https://github.com/tzinfo/tzinfo) gem:

```
$tz = TZInfo::Timezone.get("Europe/Oslo")
$tz.now # current time in Norway
```

But this is still a global change in your app and not significantly different from what you're doing.

Comment: you're right, you cannot change server time on heroku, but that should be ok. Thanks for the TZInfo tip! Doesn't touch the log question though. The logging to `production.log` is rails internal code, so I guess I'll have to open it up and change its use of `Time.now`. TZInfo won't affect Time.now, right?

Comment: No, using `tzinfo` shouldn't affect the actual server `Time`.

Answer (score 0):

I found that the above solutions did not work on Heroku.
I put this in my config/environments/production.rb
Make sure you put it before your logger is initialized

```
Rails::Rack::Logger.class_eval do
# Override logging to spit out time in different zone to easier find user reported 
errors
# https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v3.2.14/railties/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb#L38
 def started_request_message(request)
  'Started %s "%s" for %s at %s' % [
    request.request_method,
    request.filtered_path,
    request.ip,
    Time.now.in_time_zone('Melbourne') ]
 end
end
```

Comment: perhaps it doesn't, it is an old question and answer. A good solution shouldn't be a hack though, please don't be insulted by that, you show creativity.