# How do I fix the search discrepancy between local stack (Ruby 1.9.2, Rails 3, MySQL) and Heroku's stack (Ruby 1.9.2, Rails 3, PostgreSQL)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, heroku

I am having a hard time migrating from my local (MySQL-Rails3) stack to Heroku's (PostgreSQL) stack.  The code works fine on local machine but gives unwanted results on Heroku.

On my local machine:

```
tickets = Ticket.where(:created_at => (Time.now.midnight.utc)..(Time.now.end_of_day.utc))
```

For instance, if the time now is July 9 2011 10:10am (local time), the above code would return all tickets created today (between July 9 2011 05:00 UTC and July 10 2011 05:00 UTC).

But on Heroku, the same code is returning tickets created on July 9 2011 UTC regardless of the time.  So tickets created July 9 2011 00:10 UTC would be included (that would be yesterday's tickets).

My understanding is that the code should work for PostgreSQL (obvisously it doesn't).  How do I fix it so that the search criteria includes the time on PostgreSQL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you be having a timezone problem? I'd guess that Heroku instances run in UTC by default because that's really the only sensible default. You could try to [change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2719330/heroku-time-zone-problem-logging-local-server-time) your [Heroku timezone](http://ru05team.blogspot.com/2011/02/change-heroku-timezone.html):

```
$ heroku config:add TZ=where_ever/you_are
```

Also have a look at your `config.time_zone` setting.

You should also switch your development environment to PostgreSQL to match your deployment environment.

Comment: thanks for the reply. I was able to set up my local machine stack to match heroku's (PostgreSQL). The code works fine locally.  But on Heroku, its a little off.  I will have a look at the config.time_zone setting.