# Heroku Server timezone and logs time

Tags: heroku

I'm trying to change Heroku server timezone.

I've followed the steps in [Why does Heroku log using the server time rather than the Rails time zone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2719330/why-does-heroku-log-using-the-server-time-rather-than-the-rails-time-zone)

Executing `heroku config`: `TZ:                   Atlantic/Cape_Verde`

Executing `heroku run bash date`: `Wed Jan 23 11:24:52 CVT 2013`

However `heroku logs --tail` still shows dates with my local timezone GMT

Am I missing something? Thanks guys:)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As of version 6.15.5-1f03166

```
heroku config:add TZ="America/New_York"
```

worked for me. Make sure you run the command after navigating to the application directory. For the correctness of timezone, check this [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones) page.
For e.g. use

`heroku config:add TZ="Asia/Kolkata"`

to get logs in Indian Standard Time.

In case, you are not inside your project directory, Heroku-cli expects an extra flag :

```
heroku config:add TZ="Asia/Kolkata" --app appname
```

where *appname* is the app name present on your Heroku dashboard and **not** your project name.

**NOTE:** By default, updating timezone re-deploys your running application.

Comment: This worked for me :)  I used "America/Pacific" and it's now in California time, thanks!

Comment: Note: This does not work for `heroku logs`, as these are [always in UTC](https://help.heroku.com/JZKJJ4NC/how-do-i-set-the-timezone-on-my-dyno).

Answer (score 5):

If you are using a Log Viewer like PaperTrail, then one additional setting is required :
PaperTrail > Settings > Profile > TimeZone > DropDown of selectable TimeZones

Answer (score 3):

Timezone for Heroku logs cannot be changed and logs will remain in `UTC` even if you change the dyno timezone. Which is also not recommended, timezones are best handled within your application, and for logs, the log viewer can provide timzezone setting.

Heroku addons for logging - https://elements.heroku.com/addons#logging

Source: https://help.heroku.com/JZKJJ4NC/how-do-i-set-the-timezone-on-my-dyno