# What is the correct tz database time zone for India?

Tags: timezone

As I understand, India uses a single time zone for the whole country.

I looked on the Wiki page [List of tz database time zones](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones), but I was unable to find an entry for India.

Which time zone is correct to use?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_in_India

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The [`zone1970.tab`](https://github.com/eggert/tz/blob/master/zone1970.tab) file in the tz database is one way to determine the correct time zone. It currently has the following entry for India:

```
IN    +2232+08822    Asia/Kolkata
```

This breaks out to the following:

- `IN` is the [ISO-3166 alpha-2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1_alpha-2) country code for India.
- `+2232+08822` refers to the latitude and longitude of the reference point, in [ISO 6709](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_6709) format.  In this case, it is [22°32'N, 88°22'E](https://www.google.com/maps/place/22%C2%B032%2700.0%22N+88%C2%B022%2700.0%22E/@22.587206,88.4089312,11.05z/data=!4m5!3m4!1s0x0:0x0!8m2!3d22.5333333!4d88.3666667), which is in the heart of Kolkata, India.
- `Asia/Kolkata` is the IANA TZ identifier for this time zone.

Therefore, the correct time zone to use for India is **`Asia/Kolkata`**.  This is also referenced on the Wikipedia page you provided in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Timezone for Heroku logs cannot be changed and logs will remain in UTC even if you change the dyno timezone. Which is also not recommended, timezones are best handled within your application, and for logs, the log viewer can provide timzezone setting.

Heroku addons for logging - https://elements.heroku.com/addons#logging

Source: https://help.heroku.com/JZKJJ4NC/how-do-i-set-the-timezone-on-my-dyno

Just putting the same answer here from
https://stackoverflow.com/a/64493992/5056648
as this thread didnot have the updated solution